# On using "wer + relative pronoun" in German

Tags: sentence-structure, relative-clause, relative-pronoun

> **Wer** Kants Hauptwerk »Die Kritik der reinen Ver­nunft« im Original lesen möchte, sollte oder gar muß - **der** findet hier einen hilfreichen Wegbegleiter für den Einstieg in eine faszinierende, aber nicht leicht zugäng­liche Lektüre.

(Ralf Ludwig, *Kant für Anfänger: Die Kritik der reinen Vernunft*)

Is the correlation of **wer ... der** in this quotation the same as the English **he who**; and, if so, why is it separated like this in German?

Comment: "Whoever wants to read xyz finds a helping... here".

Comment: @Alex As far as I know, "whoever" translates into German as "wer auch immer."

Comment: @ΥΣΕΡ26328 In this case, "wer" equals "wer auch immer".

Comment: Btw. the hypen in the quote is wrong. But that's obviously not your mistake.

Comment: @Em1 Obviously...

Comment: They way you asked this questions, makes it necessary to have knowledge about the correct usage of "*he who*" in English, i.e. this question requires expertise of a language other than German, which makes this question off-topic here. Please edit your question and try to ask about German grammar without referring to Non-German (i.e. English) grammar. (I really would like to give an answer to your question, but I am a German native speaker, and I have no detailed knowledge about the English *"he who"* construction)

Answer (score 3):

For ease of understanding, I would translate the construction as: "Whoever X, that person Y," where X and Y are predicate clauses.

"Wer Kant lesen möchte, der findet hier..."

"Whoever wants to read Kant, that person finds here..."

There are two separate predicates (reads Kant and finds here), and that's why they are separated in German.

In English, you can use the construction, "He who reads Kant finds here..." by combining the two predicates after the combined "nominative" (he who) but in German you don't do this. You use the construction nominative predicate, nominative predicate that is wer predicate...der predicate.

Comment: ***Der, der** Kants [...] muss, findet [...]* is a common alternative following the English *He who* pattern. It seems the writer of the paragraph didn't like the doubling of *der*, though it's perfectly okay to write like that.

Comment: @Janka So my translation of it as _He who..._ is OK then, right?

Comment: *Wer* alone already translates into *He who*. The *der* introducing the second part is an optional demonstrative pronoun. This is the same in my example: the first *der* is a demonstrative pronoun, while the immediately following *der* is relative pronoun. Overstressed, it reads *Jener, welcher …*.